# Not Sure if Laravel Distinct() is What I Should Use

Tags: laravel

This might be simple but I cant seem to figure it out. Customers have many machines. I need to return just the customer name once for a list. What I'm getting is an array of all machines.

```
 public function machine_past_due(){
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $machines_past =Machine::distinct()
        ->whereDate('cert_date', '<', $today)
        ->with('customer')
        ->get();
    return response()->json($machines_past);
}
```

Comment: Please show your output to fix the issue more precisely.

Comment: I have posted a solution. Have a look.

Comment: `just the customer name once for a list` - can you clarify what this means? A list of machines?  But with customer included only once, somewhere?  What should the output look like, exactly?

Comment: @Don'tPanic If the customer has multiple machines the function above will return one row for each machine. I would like to have only one row with the customer name regardless of the number of machines.

Comment: @T.A. I see - still not sure if I am understanding correctly but I posted an answer, let me know if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to achieve your goal:

```php
 public function machine_past_due(){
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $machines_past =Machine::distinct()
        ->whereDate('cert_date', '<', $today)
        ->with('customer')
        ->get();
    $machines_past = $machines_past->pluck('customer.property_name')->unique(); //added this line
    return response()->json($machines_past);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding, and I know you already have an accepted solution, but if you want customers who have machines, it seems to me answers here are coming at it from the wrong direction - you don't want machines with customers, you want customers.

As a first step:

```
Customers::has('machines')->get();
```

will give you a list of customers who have at least 1 machine.

To incorporate your date restriction, you can [use `whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to do something like:

```
Customers::whereHas('machines', function (Builder $query) { 
    $query->whereDate('cert_date', '<', date('Y-m-d')); 
})->get();
```

This will give you all customers who have at least one machine matching the date condition.  Note it does not include the machines - just a customer list.

If you want to include a customer's machines in the results, you have to then [use `with()`, while constraining it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) with the same date condition:

```
Customers::whereHas('machines', function (Builder $query) { 
    $query->whereDate('cert_date', '<', date('Y-m-d')); 
})->with(['machines' => function($query) {
    $query->whereDate('cert_date', '<', date('Y-m-d')); 
}])->get();
```

This will give you a list of all customers who have at least one machine matching the date condition, and list each customers' machines as a property of the customer, accessible as `$customer->machines`.  You can then iterate over customers and do things like (in a blade view say):

```
@foreach ($customers as $customer)
    {{ $customer->name }}, {{ $customer->machines->count() }} machines:
    @foreach ($customer->machines as $machine)
        {{ $machine->cert_date }}
        // ... some other $machine stuff :-)
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

> force the query to only return distinct results.

This is what distinct do, here is the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L352),

so when you use distinct, it will check all the columns you selected which is duplicated.

You can use `groupBy` instead:

```php
$machines_past =Machine::groupBy('customer_id')
        ->whereDate('cert_date', '<', $today)
        ->with('customer')
        ->get();
```

---

And if you are using mysql 5.7+ and you are using strict mode in laravel, you need to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to return is an array of distinct customer names from your machine collection then laravel collection have a couple of methods that can help you. Assuming your customer is a "toOne" relationship and has a `name` attribute then:

```
public function machine_past_due(){
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $machines_past = Machine::whereDate('cert_date', '<', $today)
        ->with('customer')
        ->get();

    $customer_names = $machines_past
        ->pluck('customer.name')
        ->unique()
        ->all();

    return response()->json($customer_names);
}
```

The code will pluck the customer name from each of the machine returned from your query and removes all duplicate before finally converting it to an array.